# Javascript SDK vs PHP SDK for facebook needs

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a website (wordpress) which currently supports login via Facebook. That is accomplished by the JS SDK. I had 0 epxperience on facebook's API so i'm still trying to figure out how and where i'm going.

Now i want to do various checks before i let the user do some stuff.
For example to rate a specific item only if he has attended an event, or liked the webpage etc etc.

I'm doing pretty good so far but i was wondering if the above "actions" or "checks" if you like should be a part of the servers side.

I wanna give them the option to attend or decline an event too, but say i output 5 events, i'll have to send 5 calls to the FB graph and do some searching on the clients side so that i can use the button according to his status on the event.

I'm worried that this is going to affect the clients side a lot.

Another option would be to use the JS SDK for login purposes only and then the PHP one for the various checks and other outpus.

I am more experienced in PHP overall than JS and i'm still trying to decide which way to go.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use PHP for all of it because that's the only way you have full control over what the user does, since client-side scripts can be manipulated by the user. There's no reason why you would *need* to use JavaScript for any of it, including the login process. Facebook has a robust PHP SDK that can be used for login. There's a good tutorial on how to use it here: [Login with facebook using PHP](http://www.krizna.com/general/login-with-facebook-using-php/)

Btw, it is [against Facebook's policy](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2014/08/07/Graph-API-v2.1/) to incentivize "Liking" pages, which they refer to as like-gating:

> You must not incentivize people to use social plugins or to like a Page. This includes offering rewards, or gating apps or app content based on whether or not a person has liked a Page. It remains acceptable to incentivize people to login to your app, checkin at a place or enter a promotion on your app's Page.

Comment: Yes i remember Facebook changing it's policy a couple of months back. I know about likes so i'mma go with check ins, but do you have any idea about event attends?? Like you have to attend an event in order to say rate something ?

Comment: I found this under their [platform policy](https://developers.facebook.com/policy): "Only incentivize a person to log into your app, enter a promotion on your app’s Page, or check-in at a place. Don’t incentivize other actions." So incentivizing event attends does not appear to be permissible. Also take note that, under FB's new SDK and policy, your site will have to be reviewed before you can use FB's SDK for many purposes, so it is recommendable to follow their policy closely and not venture into any gray areas.

Comment: btw, if you found my answer helpful, please mark it as your accepted answer as this helps me build my reputation on the site :)